# Why does jetty server hangs after server start and doesn't run integration test?

Tags: maven, jetty, integration-testing

I am running integration test using maven-jetty-plugin and maven-failsafe-plugin. Here's my configuration:

```
   <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>verify</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
             </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26</version>
            <configuration>

                  <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                      <port>8080</port>
                      <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                  </connectors>

                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <scanTargetPatterns>
                    <scanTargetPattern>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.jsp</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*.html</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.page</include>
                            <include>**/*.properties</include>
                            <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </scanTargetPattern>
                </scanTargetPatterns>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>run-war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                          <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When i run **mvn clean install**, jetty server starts and after that nothing happens (it gets stuck). Last line in my logs is : [INFO] Started Jetty Server. When i press control-c, here is what it prints:

```
2013-04-25 15:24:16.315:INFO::Shutdown hook executing
2013-04-25 15:24:16.317:INFO::Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
2013-04-25 15:24:16.821:INFO:/ca-app:Shutting down log4j
2013-04-25 15:24:16.821:INFO:/ca-app:Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2013-04-25 15:24:22.108:INFO::Shutdown hook complete[INFO] 
Jetty server exiting.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.7.1:integration-test (default) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: my-app/target/failsafe-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding MacRoman, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:stop (stop-jetty) @ my-app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.7.1:verify (default) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Killing Jetty
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: my-app/target/failsafe-reports
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding MacRoman, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Installing my-app/target/ca-app-0.1.5-SNAPSHOT.war to ~/.m2/....../my-app/0.1.5-SNAPSHOT/my-app-0.1.5-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing my-app/pom.xml to ~/.m2/....../my-app/0.1.5-SNAPSHOT/my-app-0.1.5-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:sources (install) @ my-app ---
```

Why does it get stuck? When i press control-c, why does it perform rest of the steps? How can i fix it?

Comment: Similar questions was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759620/integration-tests-wouldnt-start-failsafe-maven?rq=1. There asker has commented that changing surefire-failsafe version fixed the problem for him. But, it doesn't seem to be working for me. I have commented there also.

Comment: Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **start** instead of **run-war**.

From javadoc on org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-maven-plugin\9.3.0.M2\jetty-maven-plugin-9.3.0.M2.jar!\org\eclipse\jetty\maven\plugin\AbstractJettyMojo.nonblocking

---

*Determines whether or not the server blocks when started. The default behavior (false) will cause the server to pause other processes while it continues to handle web requests. This is useful when starting the server with the intent to work with it interactively. This is the behaviour of the **jetty:run, jetty:run-war, jetty:run-war-exploded** goals.
If true, the server will not block the execution of subsequent code. This is the behaviour of the **jetty:start** and default behaviour of the **jetty:deploy** goals.*

---

Answer (score 0):

So in order to start the jetty add run:

```
<goals>
     <goal>stop</goal>
        <goal>start</goal>
</goals>
```

And the whole:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
    <configuration>
        <war>webapp/target/MyWar.war</war>
        <stopKey>fooKey</stopKey>
        <stopPort>8081</stopPort>
        <stopWait>1</stopWait>
        <httpConnector>
            <port>8888</port>
        </httpConnector>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
                <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                <stopPort>8866</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
                <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                <stopPort>8866</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```