# Maven failsafe plugin does not execute tests

Tags: integration-testing, maven-jetty-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a problem with Maven Failsafe plugin that does not execute my tests.
The test is stored in folder `\src\test\java\` and its name is `Test1IT.java` which is in the correct format.
In addition I have to exclude this test in Maven compiler plugin,because this test is dependent on jetty run.
Here is the pom.xml

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <testExcludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                        </testExcludes>
                    </configuration> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>                  
            </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

If executed `mvn verify` it builds everything, start jetty and return

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19:integration-test (integration-test) @ application ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Even though I have just implemented <configuration>
     <includes>
      <include>**/*.java</include>
     </includes>
    </configuration>
and there are still no test to run.. :( Could you help me? This is multimodule maven project

Comment: If used maven-surefire-plugin it works ok. What is the problem with maven failsafe?

Comment: Neither version change nor goal change helped as provided on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759620/integration-tests-wouldnt-start-failsafe-maven

Answer (score 1):

Actually after several hours of experimenting with Maven I was able to find working version:

Here is the pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>

            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>      
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                <stopKey>abc</stopKey>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/hellojavaworld</contextPath>           
                </webApp>    
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

Be careful about used version for maven jetty plugin. For my particular scenario the latest working version is 9.2.2.v20140723. Any newer version have malfunction. It just starts jetty and script does not continue further. I am not sure if this is a bug, but it should not happen.

Hope this post helps.